# Programatically modifying system.web/webServices/protocols configuration section

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I need to programatically add or modify the following section in an asp.net web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I could manipulate the file at the XML level, but I prefer to use the configuration API whenever possible. I found ProtocolElement and ProtocolElementCollection classes, both in the System.Web.Services.Configuration namespace and in the System.Web.Services assembly, but after much googling I can't find any usage examples. I have the system.web.extensions/scripting/webServices sectionGroup defined in the configSections element - is that sufficient, or do I need to add a config section under that?

Any help manipulating this would be appreciated. We're currently using ASP.NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with [`WebConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) and [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) classes.

You can also take a look into this question: [Changing values in Web.config with a Batch file or in .NET code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662000/changing-values-in-web-config-with-a-batch-file-or-in-net-code/664082#664082)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; however, I'm already using ConfigurationManager and WebConfigurationManager. Updating "the basics" (i.e. app settings, connection strings, etc.) is easy; it's the more esoteric parts of a web.config file (system.web, etc.) that is the challenge. I will probably go ahead and do this via XML.